# Kafka consumer poll not reading same batch even auto offset is disabled

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to understand the behavior of the kafkaConsumer.poll() method
I configured my consumer to not auto commit

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapAddress);
    KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer(properties);
```

As far as I understand, based on the Javadoc, if I do

```
    ConsumerRecords firstBatch = consumer.poll(0l);
    ConsumerRecords secondBatch = consumer.poll(0l);
```

Both `firstBatch` and `secondBatch` should contain the same `ConsumerRecords`, assuming that there is only one partition in the topic, since the offset has not been committed.
Is my assumption correct?  My problem is that each time I call `consumer.poll(0l)` the the next batch of `ConsumerRecords` are fetched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both firstBatch and secondBatch should contain the same ConsumerRecords

This is wrong, Kafka consumer offset will increase automatically for every subsequent poll even auto `offset` is disabled or `offset` is submitted manually

[**Offsets and Consumer Position**](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

> The position of the consumer gives the offset of the next record that will be given out. It will be one larger than the highest offset the consumer has seen in that partition. **It automatically advances every time the consumer receives messages in a call to poll(long)**
>
> The committed position is the last offset that has been stored securely. **Should the process fail and restart, this is the offset that the consumer will recover to.** The consumer can either automatically commit offsets periodically; or it can choose to control this committed position manually by calling one of the commit APIs (e.g. commitSync and commitAsync).

And your assumption is right in another way, when `offset` is not committed and kafka consumer is restarted it will poll the old batch or from the beginning where ever the old offset is submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I understand that there are two offsets, the one in the server Partition Topic and the one in the consumer session. The auto commit attribute defines how the offset commit is going to be handled in the server side, but the `poll()` method always moves the consumer offset.